# canvas image rotation on with center like dialer

Tags: android, android-canvas, sensors

I have a square shape image which having circle view, I am drawing that image in center of circle using canvas using below code:

```
Bitmap bitmapCompass = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.compass_rim);
  float w2= (w-bitmapCompass.getWidth())/2;
  float h2= (h-bitmapCompass.getHeight())/2;

  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapCompass, w2, h2, paint);
```

I want to rotate this image like a dialer relative to center.Facing issue to make rotation of Image around that circle center.

Used code for rotation:

```
Bitmap bitmapCompass = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.compass_back);
  float w2= (w-bitmapCompass.getWidth())/2;
  float h2= (h-bitmapCompass.getHeight())/2;
  Matrix matbitmapCompass = new Matrix();
     matbitmapCompass.postRotate((float)90);
     Bitmap bmpRotateCompass = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapCompass, 0,0, bitmapCompass.getWidth(), bitmapCompass.getHeight(), matbitmapCompass, true);
  canvas.drawBitmap(bmpRotateCompass, w2, h2, paint);
```

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to want to rotate the canvas:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(angle, rotationCenterX, rotationCenterY);
// draw here
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Please review this url http://www.xaraxone.com/webxealot/workbook11/page_4.htm I want to use same type images want to pass angle from sensor api for rotation. suppose C(h, k) are center of circle then what to do for rotation of object with defined angle, center will fix and circle will move like dialer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you will need screenCenterX and screenCenterY, which are the X and Y screen coordinates you want to draw on. Those coordinates are the ones you will want to pass to canvas.rotate. Then when you draw the bitmap you will need to draw it at screenCenterX - bitmapWidth / 2 and screenCenterY - bitmapHeight / 2 to make sure the center of the bitmap is aligned with the rotation point on the screen.

Comment: Please check shared above code, I am doing same Bitmap bitmapCompass = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.compass_rim);
  float w2= (w-bitmapCompass.getWidth())/2;
  float h2= (h-bitmapCompass.getHeight())/2;

  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapCompass, w2, h2, paint);